# pandas function not working properly for overflowing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My code adding value for empty row but it's not working if another cell text overflow inside empty row.

see the screenshot for better understand:
[image]

You can see name column text overflowing inside my sku column and my code not working for this two row. How to get ride of theme? any idea?

is there any way in pandas prevent overflowing text?

here is my code:

```
groups = df.groupby('SKU').cumcount()
groups = groups.mask(df['SKU'].eq(' '), groups+1)
df['new-sku'] = df['SKU'].replace(' ', 'FAT-null') + ('-' + groups.astype('string').str.zfill(2)).mask(groups.eq(0), '')
```

it's adding value for empty row. But I find out it's not working if another cell text overflow inside sku row.

Comment: where is your code? and the input data?

Comment: This is not a `Python` problem nor a `pandas` problem.  That's just how Excel displays overflowing text cells.  If you want column O to be blank, you need to insert a blank string there.

Comment: mozway I updated my question and added code

Comment: Tim Roberts how to do that?

Comment: You need to auto-adjust the width of column in excel based on the content from python.

Comment: @Phoenix  how to do that ?

Comment: In excel, you can make text wrap within a cell to keep it from overflowing to other cells. Under Home choose Wrap-text. You can apply it to the whole column as well.